# Error Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1 Android

Tags: android

Tengo un programa que carga datos en un `RecyclerView` pero me da un error en :

`holder.curso.setText(alumno.getCurso())`

`getCurso()` devuelve un int. Este es el método en el que me da el error. He probado a hacer un casting a string, pero nada.

Este es el error que me da:

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1 Android

este es mi código:

```
public class AlumnosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlumnosAdapter.AlumnosViewHolder>{
    List<Alumno> listaAlumnos;

    public AlumnosAdapter(List<Alumno> alumnos){
        this.listaAlumnos = alumnos;
    }

    @Override
    public AlumnosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_recycler, parent, false);
        AlumnosViewHolder holder = new AlumnosViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AlumnosViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Alumno alumno = listaAlumnos.get(position);
            holder.nombreapll.setText(alumno.getNombre() + " " +alumno.getApellidos());
            holder.area.setText(alumno.getArea());
            holder.curso.setText(String.valueOf(alumno.getCurso()));
            try{
                URL imageUrl = new URL(alumno.getFoto_perfil());
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                con.connect();
                Bitmap imagen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(con.getInputStream());
                holder.fotoPerfil.setImageBitmap(imagen);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listaAlumnos.size();
        }

        public static class AlumnosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView nombreapll;
            TextView area;
            TextView curso;
            ImageView fotoPerfil;
            public AlumnosViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                nombreapll = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre);
                area = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewArea);
                curso = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCurso);
                fotoPerfil = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFotoPerfil);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes convertir el valor que defines `alumno.getCurso()`, a `String`:

```
holder.curso.setText(alumno.getCurso());
```

ya que lo que esta sucediendo es que trata de buscar un recurso con el id que defines, el método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) también puede aceptar un id de recurso como parámetro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes cambiar a esta forma convirtiendo el valor a `String` para que no intente buscar un recurso en el proyecto y simplemente agregue el texto dentro de la vista:

```
holder.curso.setText(String.valueOf(alumno.getCurso()));
```

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Revisa en que linea ahora. @PacoPepe

Comment: En la misma linea, no ha cambiado nada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76902/discussion-between-elenasys-and-pacopepe).